# ¿Cómo poner una imagen o icono dentro de un componente NavDropDown en React-Boostrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs

Teniendo el siguiente código:

```
<Navbar>
            <Nav>
                <NavDropdown title="Entidades Logicas" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <MenuItem>
                            A
                            </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem>B
                            </MenuItem>
                </NavDropDown>
           </Nav>
</NavBar>
```

¿Cómo puedo meter una foto/icono dentro del NavDropDown?¿Mediante parametros cómo "title" o cómo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega los tags que necesites dentro de una variable y luego ésa variable la agregas a la propiedad `title` de `NavDropdown`. Por ejemplo, usar un ícono de font awesome, sería algo como esto:

```
const title =
  <span>
    <i className="fa fa-cog fa-spin"/>Entidades Logicas
  </span>

//...

<Navbar>
  <Nav>
    <NavDropdown title={title} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
      <MenuItem>
        A
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        B
      </MenuItem>
    </NavDropdown>
  </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: Si, pero no me refiero a colocarlo dentro del MenuItem exactamente, sino donde aparece el titulo del NavDropDown, es decir, que aparezca el titulo y el icono juntos.

Comment: @XXx tienes toda la razón, revisa mi actualización